# Rails: Get all associated models from has-many association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, many-to-many, associations

I need to get all associated models from the other associated model, on which I want to run query first.

For example, I got Post model and Tag model. I need to get all Posts, which associated with some Tags.
There's no problem, if I have only one Tag – just call 'tag.posts', but if I have more, then one Tag – for example, I need to do somethink like:

```
Post.where(id: PostTag.where(tag_id: some_ids).pluck(:category_id).uniq)
```

I belive that Rails have a built-in solution. So, anybody knows it?

Comment: What type of association do you have between your models? Based on your example, it looks like a `has_many :through`. And if I'm understanding you correctly are you trying to get all the posts that are associated with multiple tags?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My thought is:

```
Post.joins(:post_tags).where('post_tags.tag_id' => some_ids).uniq
```

You can make it a scope for easier reuse. I don't think there is a built-in method for this situation.

Comment: The scope can be: `scope :from_tag_ids, ->(some_ids){ joins(:post_tags).where('post_tags.tag_id' => some_ids).uniq }`